How to implement a 3D non overlapping condition for cp_model in Google or tools?
In the Google ortools we have condition for non overlapping for 2D rectangles but not for 3D Cuboids. How can I use Google ortools to implement the same? Are there any other ways of doing the same.
I am working on a project where I have to do 3D space packing.I am not sure what constraints should I add for non overlapping 3D objects.Below is the code I have:
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#---------------------------------------------------
# data
#---------------------------------------------------

data = '''
itemid    length   width   height  weight  value  color
1           11       2       1       48      1     red
2            5       4       2       9       1     green
3           12       5       2        6      1     yellow
4           10       7       1        2      1     blue
5            2       4       2       33      1     pink
6           10       1       5       13      1     cyan
7           12       7       2       29      1     magenta
8           10       5       1       49      1     black
'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
print("Input data")
display(df)

L = 12
W = 8
H = 5
M = 400

print(f"Truck's Dimension Length:{L} Width:{W} Height:{H} Maximum Capacity:{M}")

#---------------------------------------------------
# derived data
# expand to individual items
#---------------------------------------------------

l0 = df["length"].to_numpy()
b0 = df['width'].to_numpy()
h0 = df['height'].to_numpy()
w0 = df['weight'].to_numpy()
v0 = df['value'].to_numpy()
indx0 = np.arange(np.size(l0))

n = len(l0)
print(f"Number of individual items: {n}")

#---------------------------------------------------
# create rotated items
# by duplicating
#---------------------------------------------------

# six possible rotation of a 3d object
l_rot = np.concatenate((l0, l0, b0, b0, h0, h0))
w_rot = np.concatenate((b0, h0, l0, h0, b0, l0))
h_rot = np.concatenate((h0, b0, h0, l0, l0, b0))


wr = np.tile(w0, 6)
vr = np.tile(v0, 6)
indxr = np.tile(indx0, 6)

nr = 6 * n
print(f"Number of individual items (after adding rotations): {nr}")

#---------------------------------------------------
# or-tools model
#---------------------------------------------------

model = cp_model.CpModel()

#
# variables
#

# u[i] : item i is used
u = [model.NewBoolVar(f"u{i}") for i in range(nr)]

# x[i], y[i], z[i] : location of item i
x = [model.NewIntVar(0, L, f"x{i}") for i in range(nr)]
y = [model.NewIntVar(0, W, f"y{i}") for i in range(nr)]
z = [model.NewIntVar(0, H, f"z{i}") for i in range(nr)]

# l[i], w[i], h[i] : dimensions of item i
lx = [model.NewIntVar(0, L, f"lx{i}") for i in range(nr)]
ly = [model.NewIntVar(0, W, f"ly{i}") for i in range(nr)]
lz = [model.NewIntVar(0, H, f"lz{i}") for i in range(nr)]

# x2[i], y2[i], z2[i] : upper limit of interval variable
x2 = [model.NewIntVar(0, L, f"x2{i}") for i in range(nr)]
y2 = [model.NewIntVar(0, W, f"y2{i}") for i in range(nr)]
z2 = [model.NewIntVar(0, H, f"z2{i}") for i in range(nr)]

# interval variables
xival = [model.NewIntervalVar(x[i], lx[i], x2[i], f"xival{i}") for i in range(nr)]
yival = [model.NewIntervalVar(y[i], ly[i], y2[i], f"yival{i}") for i in range(nr)]
zival = [model.NewIntervalVar(z[i], lz[i], z2[i], f"zival{i}") for i in range(nr)]

#
# constraints
#
# The main idea here is: if an item is not selected, make its
# length, width, and height zero.

# u[i] = 0  ==> lx[i]=ly[i]=lz[i]=0
# u[i] = 1  ==> lx[i]=l_rot[i], ly[i]=w_rot[i], lz[i]=h_rot[i]
for i in range(nr):
    model.Add(lx[i] == l_rot[i] * u[i])
    model.Add(ly[i] == w_rot[i] * u[i])
    model.Add(lz[i] == h_rot[i] * u[i])

# only one of the six possible rotations can be used
for i in range(n):
    model.Add(sum(u[i + j * n] for j in range(6)) <= 1)

# no overlap in 3D.


# extra: this constraint helps performance enormously
model.Add(sum([l_rot[i] * w_rot[i] * h_rot[i] * u[i] for i in range(nr)]) <= L * W * H)

# weight constraint
model.Add(sum([wr[i] * u[i] for i in range(nr)]) <= M)

# objective
model.Maximize(sum([u[i] * l_rot[i] * w_rot[i] * h_rot[i] for i in range(nr)]))

#
# solve model
#
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
# log does not work inside a Jupyter notebook
solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8
rc = solver.Solve(model)
print(f"return code:{rc}")
print(f"status:{solver.StatusName()}")
print()
print(solver.ResponseStats())
print()

#
# report solution
#
if rc == cp_model.OPTIMAL or rc == cp_model.FEASIBLE:
    used = {i for i in range(nr) if solver.Value(u[i]) == 1}
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'x': [solver.Value(x[i]) for i in used],
        'y': [solver.Value(y[i]) for i in used],
        'z': [solver.Value(z[i]) for i in used],
        'length': [l_rot[i] for i in used],
        'width': [w_rot[i] for i in used],
        'height': [h_rot[i] for i in used],
        'x2': [solver.Value(x2[i]) for i in used],
        'y2': [solver.Value(y2[i]) for i in used],
        'z2': [solver.Value(z2[i]) for i in used],
        'value': [vr[i] for i in used],
        'weight': [wr[i] for i in used]})
    print(df)


Are you sure you have a real 3D packing problem ?
These are extremely rare. Usually, boxes cannot be placed freely in space. They should be stable, balanced. So the usual 3D constraints are not enough.
In that case, the best approach would be cut the z dimension in slices, and solve 2D packing in each slice.

Can you elaborate it more??
